# Правильно ли образовано прилагательное "ду́ховый"?

Tags: словообразование, прилагательные, окказионализмы

Значение: принадлежащий, свойственный духу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я возражу всем авторам. Не слишком сильно, ибо это скорее уточнение.

Слово "д**у**ховый" фиксируется некоторыми словарями.
http://kak-perevoditsya.ru/determinism
Правда не исключено, что это какое-то недоразумение, контекст не позволяет быть в чем-то уверенным, а из философии известен детерминизм **духовный** (spiritual), но никак не **"духовый"** (ghost). Тем не менее, если ставить вопрос именно так (*правильно ли образовано слово*), с такой фиксацией приходится считаться. Смысловое недоразумение не отменяет грамматической возможности.

По сути же "д**у**ховый" - это полная форма от "духов", значение отлично от "духовой". То, что полные формы в принципе могут существовать у таких прилагательных, свидетельствует пример "кленовый", "бордовый"... Правда, в таких случаях обычно начисто отсутствует краткая форма.

По сути же вопроса мне добавить особо нечего.
У слова "дух" - два значения *как минимум), от них и два прилагательных. В вашем случае используется форма **"духов".**

> А если понадобится сказать о духовых днях во множеством числе, избегая
>   соблазна переформулировать?

А какие проблемы?
Д**у**ховы дни, д**у**ховых дней, д**у**ховым дням...

Единственная сложность - здесь в косвенных падежах - полная форма прилагательного. Краткая же форма прилагательного в косвенных падежах множественного числа сейчас совершенно вышла из употребления, но теоретически можно попытаться и её реконструировать (д**у**ховов дней, д**у**ховам дням...). Но я не уверен, что для прилагательных на -ов (грамматически, да отчасти и семантически это ведь прилагательные **притяжательные**) она вообще когда-то употреблялась как самостоятельная, отличная от полной.

> в том месте, когда оно по написанию совпадает с "духовым оркестром",
>   как омоним.

Это строго говоря не омоним, а **омограф**, да и то лишь частичный, ибо произношение разное. Об ударении вам уже сказали.

UPD
**@Alex_ander** заставил меня напрячься и разобраться.
Действительно, в современной физике есть понятие "духа"(ghost), используется, правда, крайне ограниченно и у весьма своеобразных авторов. 
Встречается в понятиях, связанных с недетерминированностью объектов микромира: "ghost determinism" и "ghost contribution". Понятно, что ничего общего с духовным тут нет. Это именно **духовый детерминизм** и **духовый вклад**. Таким образом, это не фантазии некоторых авторов физических словарей. Возможно, сама идея такой предопределенности ничего общего с наукой и не имеет, но словарная фиксация налицо  - и значение слова понятно.

Comment: Мне не удалось найти гуглом сочетание ghost(-)determinism, возможно, это конструкция автора сетевого словаря, подрабатывающего по скайпу. Да и больше похоже на "привиденческий" или "призраковый".

Comment: @Alex_ander Ну я ж и сказал, что сочетание сомнительное. Хотя гуглом найти проблем не составляет вы тут погорячились. https://www.google.com/search?ei=s900W8GfGKP76ASqkqKgDA&q=%22ghost+determinism%22&oq=%22ghost+determinism%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0i8i30k1.8270.14806.0.15972.4.4.0.0.0.0.198.594.0j4.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.340...33i160k1.0.Pb7FGOBPxfU

Comment: @Alex_ander но суть же не в этом сочетании, тем более на английском... Главное, что есть фиксация слова "духовый" - явно не смешиваемом с "духовный".

Comment: @Alex_ander я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. В сети для меня это пока выгладит так, что источником "духового вклада/детерминизма" на этих немногих страницах послужил вклад пользователя Макарова в популярный сетевой словарь "Мультитран" (он открыт для свободного редактирования).

Comment: Нашёл один книжный пример: "Духовая экспансия оккультизма." - в книге _Православная церковь, католицизм, протестантизм, современные ереси и секты в России, Изд. Санкт-Петербургской митрополии, 1994._ Похоже на окказионализм: здесь понадобилось противопоставление духовному, Святого Духа - духам типа стоящего за полтергейстом. Выглядит вполне уместным в этом контексте. Но в еретических книгах о самом полтергейсте такого термина не встречается, хотя о соотв. духе подробно рассуждают.

Comment: *В сети для меня это пока выгладит так, что источником "духового вклада/детерминизма"* но помилуйте, оба английских сочетания никак не могли быть вкладом переводчика. А перевод "духовый" представляется весьма логичным. Ваш пример тут совсем не в тему, это действительно окказионализм - в лучшем случает.

Comment: "Вклад" нашёлся: это _вклад в формулу_ от величин, связанных с _"духовыми полями"_ - в рамках _теории струн_. С "детерминизмом" в реальных текстах совсем плохо - а как без них можно судить о "логичности перевода"?. Мультитран - просто коллекция случаев перевода случайными переводчиками, зачастую излишне серьёзно воспринимаемая составителями сетевых словарей.

Comment: @Alex_ander - мультитран - это ваши тараканы. Я на него не ссылаюсь. Я вижу английский термин (ghost) - и понимаю, почему у переводчика возникло желание использовать форму "духовый": чтобы избежать смешения с "духов"(spiritual). Образование позволяет мне влезть в физическую сущность проблемы и оценить точность перевода, но я принципиально не буду это делать на ресурсе, посвященном русскому языку. Вопрос для меня сводится только к тому, **правильно** ли образовано слово, а не то, что думают об этом составители уже существующих словарей..

Comment: Это не перевод английского термина, оригинальный термин "духи Фаддеева - Попова" и "духовые поля" (в значении разновидности поля) возник в русском. Переводчик ли Макаров по роду занятий, мы никогда не узнаем. Словобразование же можно признать верным (ранее в комментариях к другому ответу я связывал особенности его формы с духом в значении "вещества" - в "теории струн" контекст близкий). Однако исходный вопрос был поставлен о названных автором смыслах притяжательности и свойственности, к которым эта форма не подходит.

Comment: @Alex_ander * оригинальный термин "духи Фаддеева - Попова"*  я не знал этого, спасибо, мне просто лениво было копаться. Но это нисколько не меняет мою позицию,  скорее укрепляет, а вот ваши отсылки к мультитрану становятся вообще нелепыми.

Comment: И, кстати, я не уверен, что первоисточник, на которыц ссылается ("Feynman diagrams for the Yang-Mills field", Phys. Lett.) был написан на русском. Но и это, как уже сказал, решительно ничего не меняет в отношении оценки нормативности самого термина с точки зрения русского языка.

Answer (score 1):

За этими значениями закрепились другие слова, отличающиеся от используемых по отношению к воздуху (духовой, духовые) и запаху (душный):

Принадлежащий духу - **духовской (храм), духов (день)**

Свойственный духу, связанный с его проявлением - **духовный**

**P.S.** В гипотетической *теории струн* используется термин "**Духи Фаддева - Попова**". https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8_%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0

Им обозначаются **фиктивные** поля, соответствующие им частицы и величины (напр. лагранжиан духовых полей) в математических формулах. Соответственно, такие условные "духи" (в английской терминологии - ghosts) являются элементами материи, которая обычно трактуется как *вещество* или *поле*. Относимые к таким "материальным" духам существительные называют духовыми: **ду́ховые поля** - состоящие из духов, *духовый вклад* в математическую формулу. В оккультных источниках такая терминология не встречается.

Comment: А если понадобится сказать о духовых днях во множеством числе, избегая соблазна переформулировать? Меня интересует именно поведение слова "духов"(чей?) в том месте, когда оно по написанию совпадает с "духовым оркестром", как омоним. Есть ли на этот счёт строгое грамматическое ограничение помимо "так никогда не употребляли"?

Comment: Можно при необходимости поставить ударение. Что касается словообразования, то такая форма больше ассоциируется с материалом или цветом (духовый, ореховый, черепаховый, пуховый...), чем с притяжательностью. В сказке можно было бы допустить в этом смысле невидимые "дУховые сапоги" и т. п. Попытался было связать это слово с мусульманской молитвой Духа, но не выходит: там ударение на втором слоге :) .

Comment: @Alex_ander  А есть нарицательное название духов день, духовы дни. Ведь это праздник - Духов день,  у православных отмечается раз  в году.

Comment: Я допускаю, что у каждого индейца может быть свой духов день, причём для каждого духа отдельно :) .

Comment: У индейцев, может, и есть, а вот в наших словарях не видно, да и в Нацкорпусе тоже. А Вы встречали текстовые примеры с нарицательным значением слова?

Answer (score 0):

Слова ***духовый*** нет, но есть слово ***духовой*** (дух – дух/ов/ой): духовой оркестр и духовой шкаф.

Значение свойственности (а также  отнесенности) выражает суффикс ОВН/ЕВН: **дух – дух/овн/ый,** также вина – виновный, грех – греховный, душа – душевный, день – дневной.

Также:

День Святого Духа, **Духов день**.

Храм Сошествия Святого Духа на Даниловском кладбище (**Духовская** церковь, Святодуховская церковь, Духосошественская церковь).

Информация из Интеренета http://2017god.com/duxov-den-v-2017-godu/

Согласно Библии, на пятидесятый день после Пасхи на апостолов – учеников Христа – **сошел Святой Дух,** подаривший им возможность понимать языки мира, чтобы проповедовать в дальнейшем. В честь этого события и установлен праздник – **Духов день.** Однако в разных конфессиях праздник Святого Духа отмечается в разные дни. В католицизме этот праздник отмечается одновременно с Троицей – на пятидесятый день после Пасхи. В православии – на следующий после Троицы день, на пятьдесят первый день после Пасхи, всегда на понедельник. Именно поэтому у православных славян этот праздник имеет и второе название – Понедельник Святого Духа. ...

Comment: Jasmin, у Вас образовались два ответа на один вопрос. Надо бы один изничтожить.

Comment: Техническая ошибка, я хотела просто откорректировать ответ. А можно совсем стереть информацию?

Comment: Можно удалить содержание, добавив комментарий на несколько знаков (напр. о причине), затем удалить.

Comment: Ничего не получается, комментарии не принимаются. Раньше всё легко стиралось, почему стало нельзя сейчас?

Comment: А если временно восстановить? Под комментарием я имел в виду текст вместо удалённого содержания (пустой ответ не сохраняется).